# Ошибка инициализации при работе с org.eclipse.swt

Tags: java, eclipse, build-error, swt

Я решил установить SWT и попробовать что-либо на нём написать. Использую среду Eclipse. При компиляции проекта компилятор выдаёт такую ошибку:

> Unable to initialize main class swtTest.TestSwt Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite.

Если знаете в чём проблема - помогите!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Библиотеку `swt.jar` надо добавить в зависимости проекта. Как добавить внешние библиотеки в проект.

Для компилятора важно знать откуда брать эти классы из SWT, которые требуются во время компиляции.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite

Поскольку нет необходимой библиотеки в зависимостях проекта, то компилятор проекта не знает о существовании внешних классов библиотеки SWT, пока вы не добавите эту библиотеку `swt.jar` в зависимость проекта (Build Path).

Название библиотеки может иметь другое имя, если попытаться вытащить ее из платформы Eclipse.

Вот пример как добавить нужные зависимости к проекту и начать кодировать: [Как импортировать библиотеку SWT в Eclipse Workspace](https://csharpcoderr.com/5675/)

> Чтобы разработать приложение SWT в среде Eclipse, мы должны вручную импортировать библиотеку SWT в Eclipse Workspace.
>
> Вот шаги для импорта библиотеки SWT
>
> 1. Щелкните правой кнопкой мыши на Java Project — выберите Свойства
> 2. Нажмите Путь сборки Java -> Библиотеки -> Добавить переменную -> Настроить переменную
> 3. Нажмите New -> Введите имя новой переменной «SWT_LIB» в поле «Имя».
> 4. Нажмите Файл и перейдите к файлу библиотеки SWT.
>
> SWT библиотека находится в папке плагинов Eclipse, ее имя обычно форматируется как org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_versionnumber.jar
>
> Например,
>
> D: /J2EE/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.3.2.v3347a.jar

Comment: Спасибо! Решение простое.